# Is it possible to kill an app from recent apps screen by swiping using Appium on Android?

Tags: java, android, appium

I am trying to use Touchaction by by defining start point and endpoint, but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
public static void swipeVertical(AppiumDriver driver, double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, double anchorPercentage, int duration) throws Exception {

    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int anchor = (int) (size.width * anchorPercentage);
    int startPoint = (int) (size.height * startPercentage);
    int endPoint = (int) (size.height * finalPercentage);
    new TouchAction(driver).press(anchor, startPoint).waitAction(duration).moveTo(anchor, endPoint).release().perform();

    //In documentation they mention moveTo coordinates are relative to initial ones, but thats not happening. When it does we need to use the function below
    //new TouchAction(driver).press(anchor, startPoint).waitAction(duration).moveTo(0,endPoint-startPoint).release().perform();
}

swipeVertical(driver,0.9,0.1,0.5,3000);
```

Comment: I'm not able to comment on your specific code or help you as I don't have an environment setup right now, but yes, this can work (I've done it before).

I would caution you, however, that the Recent Apps screen can differ based on SDK.

This is also very flaky design. A better method would be to use the terminateApp function, but if your test case requires using Recent Apps, you've got to do what you've got to do. I'd then, however, argue you're testing the OS and not your application.

Comment: Hey, I doubt that swipe will work in recent app screen as recent app screen is part of device but your driver is initialized for your app. May be after going in background you have to set you driver to recent app bundle id. then you above mentioned function will work. refer this link:  https://appiumpro.com/editions/13-switching-between-ios-apps-during-a-test

Answer (score 1):

Key presses on appium are done by

`driver.press_keycode(code)`

[All  required codes can be found here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

- 187 - KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH

Try this, not sure whether it solves